# Join method of thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I noticed funny behaviour  of `Join` method which is very confusing, Multithreading is possibly obsolete and outdated (after lambda/streams of java 8 ) but still curious to find out if I am missing something, never used threading in real time projects.

```
class JoinDemoThread1 implements Runnable {
    String threadName;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Testing in demothread1=" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class JoinDemoThread2 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Testing in demothread2=" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class JoinDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JoinDemoThread1 joinDemoThread1 = new JoinDemoThread1();
        JoinDemoThread2 joinDemoThread2 = new JoinDemoThread2();

        Thread demoThread1 = new Thread(joinDemoThread1);
        Thread demoThread2 = new Thread(joinDemoThread2);

        demoThread1.start();
        demoThread2.start();

        // wait for threads to end
        try {
            demoThread1.join();
            demoThread2.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }

        System.out.println("Ending Main program.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? And "Multithreading is possibly obsolete and outdate" is not true whatsoever.

Comment: You say you see "funny behaviour" but you don't explain what you mean by that, and your code doesn't explain what's funny about the behaviour. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: Hi, Apologies for not been clear, what i meant that these days mostly multithreading is achieved with latest api like stream/concurrent/Lambda may not be like jdk1.5 using old style. My assumption was Join will  make demoThread1 to run first then  demoThread2 and then finally main,  which is not happening , possibly think that main thread is expected to run at last which is happening correctly but demoThread2 and demoThread1 order is not maintained when ran few time on my mac, not sure if it is excepted behaviour. Cheers

Comment: @raky your assumption is not based on any reasons.

Comment: Calling `join()` means that the main thread is going to wait until the thread it joins on, finishes. But the threads are still running concurrently, so there is no guarantee that thread 1 and 2 run in a specific order.

Comment: On a side note, the name `JoinDemoThread1` is very confusing, as this is not a `Thread` but a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

Output when running the given code:

```
Testing in demothread1=0
Testing in demothread1=1
Testing in demothread1=2
Testing in demothread1=3
Testing in demothread1=4
Testing in demothread2=0
Testing in demothread2=1
Testing in demothread2=2
Testing in demothread2=3
Testing in demothread2=4
Ending Main program.
```

Sure it looks like there's no multi-threading going on at all. This is because your thread finishes so fast that there's no reason for the scheduler to interleave threads. If there's a more intensive process, you will see a more expected output.

For example when delaying threads a bit:

```
class JoinDemoThread2 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            System.out.println("Testing in demothread2=" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Testing in demothread2=0
Testing in demothread1=0
Testing in demothread1=1
Testing in demothread2=1
Testing in demothread1=2
Testing in demothread2=2
Testing in demothread1=3
Testing in demothread2=3
Testing in demothread1=4
Testing in demothread2=4
Ending Main program.
```